# Can visible light be emitted from a non-thermal source?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, thermal-radiation, radio

I was reading about thermal and non-thermal radiation and I was wondering if visible light can be emitted from a non-thermal source?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, LED's, [luminescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescence) of phosphorous (CRT screens), most of the current screen technology, fluorescent lights. They aren't a thermal source. They heat up due to the electric current but that's not the working principle.

Comment: Just wanted to add lasers that operate in the visible frequency range.

Comment: LEDs, too, produce light without much heat (i.e., the heat production is not directly tied to the light, as with black-body thermal radiation like the Sun or an incandescent bulb).

Comment: @PhilPerry Yeah, that's mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Super-continuum sources are well known non-thermal white light sources. The gist is a laser beam interacts with a specially tailored nonlinear material to generate ultra-broadband coherent light. A few references:

[Supercontinuum light](http://www.physicstoday.org/resource/1/phtoad/v66/i7/p29_s1?bypassSSO=1)

[Demonstration of Stimulated Supercontinuum Generation – An Optical Tipping Point](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4066.pdf)

[Generation of a 650 nm - 2000 nm Laser Frequency Comb based on an Erbium-Doped Fiber Laser](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1855)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A single atom can emit visible light and certainly is not a thermal source. My favorite example of non-thermal source of visible light is the Crab Nebula (remnant of supernova 1054), where light is generated by synchrotron mechanism.